# 3-way merge tools for Mac that show 4 panes

Tags: git, macos, mercurial, merge

I'm a fan of the [4-pane approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621475/three-way-merge-different-philosophies/2621736#2621736) to 3-way file merging.  In particular, being able to see Branch A, Branch B, and the ancestor of A and B in 3 read-only panes, then a 4th read-write pane which shows the results of your merge.

However, I've been unable to find a 4-pane merge tool for Mac OSX that I can integrate with mercurial/git.  Does such a beast exist?

Comment: It's not actually clear to me what you mean when you say that you are a fan of the 4-pane approach (the linked question is about two different 4-pane approaches, and it's not clear which one you want). Having said that, take a look at [kdiff](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) and see if that does the trick.

Comment: I believe the linked question has two different 3-way diff approaches: one is 3-pane, and the other is 4-pane.  I prefer the 4-pane

Comment: Here is a [screen shot](http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php?zz=screenshot&shot=TextMerge) of what I think he means by a 3-Way Merge with 4 Panes.

Comment: kdiff3's mac interface and command line integration leaves much to be desired compared to other tools, but yes, that's what I mean by 4 panes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The tool you are looking for is [p4merge](https://gist.github.com/1510148).  Git has native support for it.

Comment: I've been using DeltaWalker, and I really missed the 4 pane merge. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

My first thought was to suggest [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/), since it does have 4 panes for 3-way merges and can be integrated with git (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957630/how-do-you-merge-in-git-on-windows) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255202/how-do-i-view-git-diff-output-with-visual-diff-program)), but from the comments you seem to not consider it an option. I am a bit curios why, because I like KDiff3 a lot and it fits my needs.

Comment: It's not not an option per se, but I find it much clunkier than say FileMerge.app, Changes.app, or Araxis Merge.  It also spits a lot of cruft out on the command line when you call it from the terminal or from within hg merge.

Comment: I my experience kdiff3 looks less polished but does do the job perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

**VIM!**

see [macvim.org](http://macvim.org)

Comment: macvim.org hasn't been updated since 2009.  Check out http://code.google.com/p/macvim/ for the updated version.

Comment: a vim plugin for 4-pane merging (base, local, remote, output) is https://github.com/sjl/splice.vim (however no commits since 11/2013)